# Split a dataframe column in multiple columns based on multiple occurrences of a separator in R

Tags: r

My data looks like

```
a  
a >> b  
d >> c >> e
```

(unknown times ">>") can be present in a row
And I need them in several columns depending on occurrences of ">>"
I tried strsplit, which converts the column in a list and when I tried to unlist it, it repeats the values like

```
X1 X2 X3   
a  a  a  
a  b  a  
d  c  e
```

Is there any Base R solution to get

```
X1 X2 X3  
a  
a  b  
d  c  e
```

And so on? I can only use Base R!!

Comment: Please share your sample input with `dput` so we can see the structure we're working with. `dput(your_sample)`.

Comment: @Pushkar, if the answer below solves your problem do consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) or voting on it. If it doesn't, consider clarifying what is still unresolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input is a character vector as below, try this:

```
x = c("a"  ,
"a >> b"  ,
"d >> c >> e")


s = lapply(strsplit(x, split = ">>"), trimws)
s = t(sapply(s, function(x) {length(x) <- max(lengths(s)); x}))
s
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,] "a"  NA   NA  
# [2,] "a"  "b"  NA  
# [3,] "d"  "c"  "e"
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Congrats on passing 100k! Have you gotten your swag yet? I wonder whether there's any advantage to `t(s/v-apply)` since the desired output is a matrix anyway.

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 Thanks! No, nothing yet - I did get a congratulatory email but no mention of swag. I wonder if the threshold was raised.

Comment: Good call on the `t(sapply())` - saves a step.

Comment: @GregorThomas, strange. There was a post somewhat recently in Meta SE that [swag is back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358195/swag-is-coming-back).